# How would I do this JQuery in Javascript (Form Validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have this animate.css library and theres a "animated shake" class I want to use for form validation whenever a form is entered incorrectly, I'm new to JQuery, and I'd rather do it with JavaScript because know it better. I tried it with JQuery but I only know how to do it onclick instead of checking for error and applying the animation continuously when there is error on submit which is what I want to do with javascript

This is what I have for JQuery

```
         $("#firstname").addClass("animated shake").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
            function(){
                $(this).removeClass('animated shake');
            });
```

This is my incomplete JavaScript, long story short I want to keep adding the "animated shake" class when the form is not valid

```
function nameSubmit(){ 

 var x = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

if (x == "x"){

        (document.getElementById("firstname").className = "text animated shake");   
}
```

Comment: so you would like the input box to shake continuously, rather than shake and then stop?

Comment: Not continuously but shake every time the from is submitted wrong, usually it would just shake once instead of every time the field is entered wrong

Comment: I sure its a matter of adding and removing the class, I just don't know how

Comment: So you want to animate when a submit button is clicked, or validate on each keypress? But your jQuery looks ok to me. It may be easier to just use a setTimeout for 1000 ms, as that is how long (most of) the animate.css animations last (its in the source). Or are you asking for a non-jQuery solution?

Comment: @Jay S. when the submit button is clicked, and Id rather do it in javascript because its my strongest language, just so you understand, I used "x" in my javascript to check if the text field contains an x, if it does it will shake when the submit button is clicked and I want to to shake each time the x is present and the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for...

```
function nameSubmit(){ 
  var el = document.getElementById("firstname"); 
  var x = el.value;
  if (x == "x"){
          var origClasses = el.className;
          el.className += " animated shake";
          setTimeout(function(){
            el.className = origClasses;
          },1000);
  }
}
```